# Switched mode power supply design (I)

Tags: pcb, switch-mode-power-supply

Using switched mode power supply on a PCB seems to be quite a lot of work since we need to choose so many components and make sure that the PCB layout is done correctly.

This brings me to specific question. When we say Switched Mode Power Supply design, is that designing the actual IC that we put on the PCB, or is it how we use the IC with other components to get specific performance on a PCB?

EDIT:
My question can be reworded like this:
Is SMPS design merely the design of the controller IC, or is it design of the entire circuit that shall go on the PCB for a specific project? What does SMPS design engineer do?

Comment: Remember the point of these controller ICs is to make the design of the overall supply easier, because a lot of the work is done by the IC designers instead of you. In fact, that's the point of *every* IC.

Answer (score 8):

> Using switched mode power supply on a PCB seems to be quite a lot of work since we need to choose so many components and make sure that the PCB layout is done correctly.

A little secret: a lot of those supplies are barely modified application circuits from the datasheets or app notes of the ICs that control the supply, or simplified copies of the evaluation kits.

And often that’s not even a bad thing: you’d hope good engineering went into those designs.

Component selection is also an issue in making high performance linear low-dropout regulators work well too.

Things are really easy only if you’re designing linear supplies with 3-terminal regulators from the late 70s/early 80s, or eg. SimpleSwitcher-like ICs that were specifically designed for ease of use.

For anything more complex than a 7805 or similar, you need to do design work either way. Many people don’t and pretend it’s not a problem.

If you want a well-performing supply, it doesn’t matter if it’s linear or switching. In some cases linear is harder since you have to deal with way more heat dissipation, so thermal engineering and component life is more complex in those.

> is that designing the actual IC that we put on the PCB

Not usually, no. But as an example, I built a few supplies that are entirely controlled by a micro controller, with no SMPS ICs used at all. There is still control loop design - but it’s implemented all in software, instead of in a fixed-function SMPS controller. It gets even more complex when said microcontroller is controlling a supply that powers it - startup is an “interesting” problem, since there’s comparatively little power available until the switcher gets running, so there’s some sequencing involved in starting it up and shutting it down cleanly.

Comment: I can see that linear supplies are straightforward. The SMPS seem to be an order of maginitude complex due to the component selection process and PCB layout that must be done judiciously. So I guess if a person is making a new PCB and has no evaluation kit to copy design from, they are in deep trouble?

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 I wouldn't say that. If you choose your controller IC well, it can be very simple--LT, Maxim, and TI in particular I know make datasheets with step-by-step design guides and, frequently, layout examples.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 Judicious PCB layout is a must for everything if you're a professional. IMHO, SMPSs are "neither here nor there" - they are not significantly harder than anything else in terms of layout. You have to be competent either way.

Answer (score 7):

"Switched mode power supply (SMPS)" is a generic name, a big umbrella.

The design of an SMPS covers all the steps from topology selection to magnetics components design (or selection), from circuit design to cost optimisation, from PCB design to EMC (if required), and so forth.

The IC, as Andy stated in his answer, is a controller that helps to regulate the output (voltage, current, or power). And IC design is almost always out of scope because it's obviously a different process. But IC **selection** is a part of the entire design process. Because it's crucial to select one that fits best in terms of cost, availability, space and performance.

Answer (score 5):

A switched mode power supply is a circuit that usually contains a switch mode power supply **controller**.

> *When we say Switched Mode Power Supply design, is that designing the
> actual IC that we put on the PCB, or is it how we use the IC with
> other components to get specific performance on a PCB?*

- The IC is the **controller**
- The whole circuit is the **Switched Mode Power Supply** (containing a controller)
- The Switched Mode Power Supply design is the design of the whole circuit but, not the design activities undertaken by chip supplier

Comment: To nitpick slightly, the IC may be more than just the controller--many of them have integrated switches as well, to the point that distributors often seem to have a separate category for just the ones with integrated switches.